# Force image extension on right click save

Tags: image, web-services, right-click

I'm having some issues with images on my site which I'm downloading from an image delivery service.

They're displaying perfectly fine, but the issue comes if a user tries to right click and save the image. The images seem to be leaving off the image extension. Is there any way to force the image to download as, say a jpg? I've looked at the download attribute, but I think that's only valid on links, so it's not valid in this case.

Comment: The answer to your question probably depends on the image delivery service, and how you are using it in your web site. Please provide some of the details.

Comment: Well, it actually turns out my mac was just hiding the extensions on me in the save dialog.